# Type Name or Alias via Reflection for TT Code Generation

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I was working on some TT code generation to get rid of mundane C# codings in VS2013 Express Edition, and after researching online, created the following helper methods to facilitate Type declarations.

I am able to use it successfully in my code generation but wonder if they can be improved further or if there's any scenario which they do not cater for.

```
public static String GetActualTypeName(Type type, bool bAlias = true, bool bFullQualified = false)
{
    Type nullable = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
    String name = null;

    if (nullable != null) // handles Nullable types
    {
        name = (bAlias) ? GetAliasName(nullable, bFullQualified)
            : (bFullQualified) ? nullable.FullName : nullable.Name;

        return String.Format("{0}?", name);
    }

    if (!type.GenericTypeArguments.Any()) // handles non generic types
    {
        name = (bAlias) ? GetAliasName(type, bFullQualified)
            : (bFullQualified) ? type.FullName : type.Name;

        return name;
    }

    name = (bFullQualified) ? type.FullName : type.Name;

    // recrusive looping into generic type tree for the required type names 
    String[] names = type.GenericTypeArguments
        .Select(t => GetActualTypeName(t, bAlias, bFullQualified))
        .ToArray();         

    return String.Format("{0}<{1}>", name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf('`')), String.Join(",", names));
}

public static String GetAliasName(Type type, bool bFullQualified = false)
{
    String alias = null;

    using (var provider = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider())
    {
        var typeRef = new System.CodeDom.CodeTypeReference(type);

        alias = provider.GetTypeOutput(typeRef);
    }

    int index = alias.LastIndexOf(".");

    if (bFullQualified || index == -1)
        return alias;

    return alias.Substring(index + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
bool bAlias
```

Don't use [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) on names. When you look at the parameter, you can already see that it's a `bool`, there is no reason to repeat that in the name.

---

```
String name = null;
```

Since it seems you never want to use that `null` value, don't initialize the variable at all.

Also, it's more common to write `string` instead of `String`.

---

```
name = (bAlias) ? GetAliasName(nullable, bFullQualified)
    : (bFullQualified) ? nullable.FullName : nullable.Name;
```

What's the point of the parentheses around `bAlias` and `bFullQualified`. They don't seem to serve any purpose.

---

```
String[] names = type.GenericTypeArguments
    .Select(t => GetActualTypeName(t, bAlias, bFullQualified))
    .ToArray();
```

I think `names` is too general here. I think something like `typeArgumentNames` would be better here (even if it's significantly longer).

Also, `String.Join()` can accept `IEnumerable<string>`, so the `ToArray()` is unnecessary here.

---

```
name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf('`'))
```

Wouldn't this be more readable as `` name.Split('`')[0] ``? (It would also be less efficient, but that might not matter to you.)

---

```
String.Join(",", names)
```

I realize this is for generated code, so beauty does not matter much, but I would still prefer to add a space between the type arguments, i.e. `String.Join(", ", names)`.

---

```
using (var provider = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider())
```

Neither [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/microsoft/csharp/csharpcodeprovider.cs,22b16a467d925ab7) not its base class, [`CodeDomProvider`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/codedom/compiler/CodeDOMProvider.cs,7b108a09d4a41cb7) override `Dispose()`, it's only there because they inherit from `Component`.

This means that there is no need to use `using` here. But even if you know this, you might still choose to include the `using`, just to be on the safe side.

Also, since you're already using `CSharpCodeProvider` for this, why not use it to replace your whole `GetActualTypeName()`? You would lose the choice of specifying the form of the output, but it might be worth it for so much simplification.

Comment: "It's more common to use `string` instead of `String`"... I'd just like to add that some people like to use lower case for declaring a type and uppercase when calling the class's static methods.

Answer (score 2):

I'll accept one ternary condition, but they really shouldn't be nested.

> ```
> if (!type.GenericTypeArguments.Any()) // handles non generic types
> {
>     name = (bAlias) ? GetAliasName(type, bFullQualified)
>         : (bFullQualified) ? type.FullName : type.Name;
>
>     return name;
> }
> ```

If you're going to insist on it, why bother using a variable? Just return it directly. I really do recommend being a little more verbose here though. We don't get any extra points for writing hard to read on liners.

```
if (!type.GenericTypeArguments.Any())
{
    if (bAlias)
    {
        return GetAliasName(type, bFullQualified);
    }
    else
    {
        return (bFullQualified) ? type.FullName : type.Name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Agreed on the verbose aspect. Guess it's bit of "old habit die hard". Thanks!